# How to Change dictionary?

Tags: android-studio

I would like to resolve "Typo: in word..." that Android Studio (AS) show ever time I use words in my langage. I suppose there should be a way to add portuguese dictionary to AS but I could not find this option. Thanks for your help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-You can add a suppress warning annotation over the words that are highlighted as having a typo like so:

```
@SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
    private String exemplo;
```

-If you don't want to be adding that annotation in many places, you can deactivate the spellcheck:
`Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Inspections > Spelling` and untick the `typo` option.

-If you want to add your own dictionary, you can go to `Android Studio > Preferences > Editor > Spelling` and click the cross sign to add a custom dictionary under `Custom Dictionaries`. You'll notice that there's already an `English.dic` in the bundled dictionaries. You need the Portuguese equivalent. Just search google for `Portuguese dictionary .dic` and you'll find a few.